# Javascript current hour to use specific stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, time, stylesheet

I use the following code to get the current hour of the client and to know if it's AM or PM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//get client time
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 06 && d.getHours() <= 18){
    var dayStatus = "day";
    document.write("day");
}else{
    var dayStatus = "night";
    document.write("night");
}
</script>
```

I figured out how to find out if it's AM or PM for the client but I want to use different css stylesheet whether it's day or night. How could I do this?

This is what I got in my html HEAD so far which obviously does not work, just need to know how to make it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(dayStatus = "day"){
    <link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}else{
    <link href="includes/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
</script>
```

Comment: You do know that your HEAD code should be using `document.write()` like you did in your first example? Like: `document.write("<link href=\"includes/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />");`

Comment: Also your `if` condition should be `dayStatus == "day"`, not `dayStatus = "day"`. You're doing an assignment instead of a comparison.

Comment: Oopsie, did not see. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a (server-side) session using JavaScript. You really need to do this server-side. If you need the clients time, you will need to post it to the server using AJAX. There are, however, two easier ways of doing it:

Client-sided:

```
if (isDay) {
    document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="url/to/day.css" />');
} else {
    document.write('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="url/to/night.css" />');
}
```

Server-sided:

```
if ($isDay) {
    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="url/to/day.css" />';
} else {
    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="url/to/night.css" />';
}
```

Comment: Sounds pretty obvious, thanks. Could you advice me to specific articles that could push me into the right direction?

Comment: @45808: What is it you're having problems with, exactly? Is is AJAX or PHP sessions?

Comment: I don't really know AJAX that well. I want a specific CSS stylesheet to be used when it's day on the client side or an other one when it's night. First I thought it would be handy to use a PHP session but on the other hand there may be easier methods.

I just figured out how to check the hours in javascript and to check whether it's day or night, but now I need to know how to use that specific stylesheet.

Comment: @45808: You can do that using JavaScript only without using AJAX at all. Calculate wether it is day or night and decide what stylesheet is required. Then create a `<script>` node, set its `src` attribute to the respective file and add it to the `<head>`.

Comment: I edited my first post with more code. I tried setting the specific css stylesheet but not sure how to do this in JS.

Comment: @45808: Another approach would be to do the same server-side. That would have the benefit of faster page-load. The only drawback might be, that the server-time is the same across all users (think of users in other time-zones).

Comment: That was my original idea too but I thought it would be 'cooler' if it actually changed for users time. I may reconsider it though. Did you see my first post again for the code?

Comment: Wrap your <link>s in document.write()

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you forget the date calculation on the client, and instead (on page load) make an AJAX call to a PHP script that will determine whether or not to start the session?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, will your users be on the same page for a long period of time or be moving around? If they are moving around then simply have the PHP function that will execute on the page load and then determine if to create a new session. Or if not then run a Javascript function on a timer that sends a GET request to a php script which then determines if to create a new session.

Comment: All I want is to check if it's AM or PM for the user and use a specific css stylesheet to change the design of the website. Should not matter if users are on the same page or not. It also does not have to change immediately with AJAX when the time changes from AM to PM.