# Changing the background-color at different hours of the day in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the `body` background color at different times of the day?

This is my script, but nothing is showing on my page. I am really new to JavaScript. Can you explain what's wrong?

```js
var t = date("H");

if (t < "10") {
    console.log("Have a good morning!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
} elseif (t < "20") {
    console.log("Have a good day!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else {
    console.log("Have a good night!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Look at your browser's console. You have numerous errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript current hour to use specific stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870098/javascript-current-hour-to-use-specific-stylesheet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple mock-up.

Depending on what time local-time, it will change the background color and text.

I've also made it so it re-checks every minute,. So if you keep the page open it will change color as the time changes.

With a little bit more effort, you could maybe even make it tween between colors during the day.

I've also removed the `document.write`, that's bad practise try not to use.  In here I've use `querySelector` on a div to show text.

```js
function updateBackground() {
  var 
    hr = (new Date()).getHours(),
    body = document.body,
    bstyle = body.style,    
    hello = document.querySelector(".hello");    
  if (hr < 10) {
    bstyle.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    bstyle.color = "black";
    hello.innerText = "Have a good morning";
  } else if (hr < 20) {
    bstyle.backgroundColor = "green";
    bstyle.color = "white";
    hello.innerText ="Have a good day!";
  } else {
    bstyle.backgroundColor = "black";
    bstyle.color = "white";
    hello.innerText = "Have a good night!";
  } 
}

setInterval(updateBackground, 1000 * 60);
updateBackground();
```

```css
.hello {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Done your homework for you :)

```js
var t = new Date().getHours();
if (t < 10) {
    document.write("Have a good morning!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
} else if (t < 20) {
    document.write("Have a good evening!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="orange";
} else {
    document.write("Have a good night!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="grey";
}
```

Check out more about [Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) functions in javaScript https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

Comment: Thanks, seems I overlooked a clumsy mistake :) Though truthfully I am not a student, just a self-teaching individual.

Answer (score 3):

There were several issues in your JavaScript. Try opening the console in your browser to get some helpful error messages.

Corrected code below:

```html
<script>
var t = new Date().getHours();

if (t < 10) {
    document.write("Have a good morning!");
} else if (t < 20) {
    document.write("Have a good day!");
} else {
    document.write("Have a good night!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple example using jQuery.

```
$(function() {

  var current_date = new Date();
  var hour = current_date.getHours();

  if(hour < 10) {
    $('body').addClass('day');
  } else {
    $('body').addClass('midday');
  }

});
```

https://codepen.io/Pauloscorps/pen/BmBGoe

Comment: Who mentioned jQuery? Why would you want to use a huge library for a simple task like this?

Comment: Moreover, over this guy is struggling with basic syntax.. Keep it simple for now.

Answer (score -2):

```
var x = new Date().getHours();

if(x < 10){
// add background for morning
}



else if(x > 10 && x < 19){
// add background for day
}

else if(x > 19){
// add background for Night
}
```

Comment: Please, consider adding some explanations to you answer. Code alone does not look good

Comment: Can you tell me what are the mistakes in the code, Its just simple sudo code to change the background image

Comment: My comment is not about the code but about your post. This is an answer to a question. It will look much better if you provide some text explanations regarding what is wrong in topicaster's code and then your solution.

As for the code it seems look ok at first glance. However, I'd use switch instead of cascade of ifs